# Using Directory.GetFiles with regex-like filter

Tags: c#

I have a folder with two files:

- Awesome.File.20091031_123002.txt
- Awesome.File.Summary.20091031_123152.txt

Additionally, a third-party app handles the files as follows:

- Reads a `folderPath` and a `searchPattern` out of a database
- Executes `Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, searchPattern)`, processing whatever files match the filter in bulk, then moving the files to an archive folder.

It turns out that I have to move my two files into different archive folders, so I need to handle them separately by providing different searchPatterns to select them individually. Please note that I can't modify the third-party app, but I can modify the searchPattern and file destinations in my database.

**What `searchPattern` will allow me to select `Awesome.File.20091031_123002.txt` without including `Awesome.File.Summary.20091031_123152.txt`?**

Comment: Are they always of the format `Name.File.date_time.txt` and `Name.File.Summary.date_time.txt` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Awesome.File.????????_??????.txt

The question mark (?) acts as a single character place holder.

Answer (score 10):

If your were going to use LINQ then...

```
  var regexTest = new Func<string, bool>(i => Regex.IsMatch(i, @"Awesome.File.(Summary)?.[\d]+_[\d]+.txt", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
  var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\path\to\folder").Where(regexTest);
```

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to try my meager linq skills here... I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but here's mine:

```
string pattern = ".SUMMARY.";
string[] awesomeFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("path\\to\\awesomefiles");

        IEnumerable<string> sum_files = from file in awesomeFiles
                                        where file.ToUpper().Contains(pattern)
                                        select file;

        IEnumerable<string> other_files = from file in awesomeFiles
                                        where !file.ToUpper().Contains(pattern)
                                        select file;
```

This assumes there aren't any other files in the directory other than the two, but you can adjust the pattern here to suit your needs (i.e. add "Awesome.File" to the pattern start.)

When you iterate the collection of each, you should get what you need.

Comment: *sniff* I started answering before I saw the acceptance.  Oh well.  Enjoy if you can use :).

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx), *searchPattern* only supports the ***** and **?** wildcards.  You would need to write your own regex filter that takes the results of Directory.GetFiles and applies further filtering logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Linq, here's one way.

```
public void FileChecker(string filePath)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
    int _MatchCounter;
    string RegexPattern = "^[a-zA-Z_a-zA-Z_a-zA-Z_0-9_0-9_0-9.csv]*$";
    Regex RegexPatternMatch = new Regex(RegexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    foreach (FileInfo matchingFile in di.GetFiles())
    {
        Match m = RegexPatternMatch.Match(matchingFile.Name);

        if ((m.Success))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(matchingFile.Name);
            _MatchCounter += 1;
        }
    }
}
```