# C# Directory.GetFiles with mask

Tags: c#, linq, getdirectories

In C#, I would like to get all files from a specific directory that matches the following mask:

- prefix is `"myfile_"`
- suffix is some numeric number
- file extension is `xml`

i.e

```
myfile_4.xml 
myfile_24.xml
```

the following files should not match the mask:

```
_myfile_6.xml
myfile_6.xml_
```

the code should like somehing this this (maybe some linq query can help)

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "???");
```

Thanks

Comment: I would just loop through the results and apply my own logic to determine if I should process it or not. Obviously the file type filter is easy enough to apply to the `GetFiles`, then do the extra testing in the loop

Comment: Yes you should be able to use "myfile_*.xml" in the `GetFiles()` to vastly reduce the number of filenames returned, and then provide an extra filter using a regexp.

Comment: @cheedep That's a different question. He's not asking for multiple filters.

Comment: Also in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669892/using-directory-getfiles-with-regex-like-filter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not good with regular expressions, but this might help -

```
var myFiles = from file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder, "myfile_*.xml")
              where Regex.IsMatch(file, "myfile_[0-9]+.xml",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) //use the correct regex here
              select file;
```

Comment: i am getting exception 'illegal characters in path' when running this code. how come?

Comment: edited the answer to put the folder in the Directory.Getfiles() method. Sorry, missed it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\test", "myfile_*.xml");
//This will give you all the files with `xml` extension and starting with `myfile_`
//but this will also give you files like `myfile_ABC.xml`
//to filter them out

int temp;
List<string> selectedFiles = new List<string>();
foreach (string str in files)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str);
    string[] tempArray = fileName.Split('_');
    if (tempArray.Length == 2 && int.TryParse(tempArray[1], out temp))
    {
        selectedFiles.Add(str);
    }
}
```

So if your Test folder has files:

```
myfile_24.xml
MyFile_6.xml
MyFile_6.xml_
myfile_ABC.xml
_MyFile_6.xml
```

Then you will get in `selectedFiles`

```
myfile_24.xml
MyFile_6.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"myfile_\d+.xml");

IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\").Where(fileName => reg.IsMatch(fileName));
```