# How Do I get Files From C# Directory

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get all files with prefix 009 from a  server path.
But my code  retrieving all files with 0000 prefix not specifically that starts with 009.

For example, I have files "000028447_ ghf.doc","0000316647 abcf.doc","009028447_ test2.doc","abcd.doc".

```
string [] files =Directory.GetFiles(filePath,"009*.doc)
```

is giving me all files except "abcd.doc". But I need "009028447_ test2.doc" instead.
If im giving Directory.GetFiles(filePath,"ab*.doc) it will retrieve "abcd.doc", and working as fine.But When im trying to give a pattern like "009"or "00002" it wont work as expected.

Comment: Are you **SURE** you're getting all files with 009*.doc? I'd seriously double check this assertion with a small test program...

Comment: please reformat you question and show a bit more of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Directory.GetFiles with mask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664756/c-sharp-directory-getfiles-with-mask)

Comment: @Alexander,Dear Alex, code is simple one.Reading a shared folder with System.IO.Directory

Comment: @Set No ,both are different .What Im trying to say is it will work for search patterns which have alphabets like abc or_abc .But for 00004 and similar ones it wont work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is missing a closing quote-character in the pattern. The code should be:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "009*.doc");
```

Other than that, it seems to be working as intended. I've tested this by creating a folder with the files you mention in the question:

[image: Contents of testfolder]

Next I created a console application, which uses your code to find the files, and prints all the results to the console. The output is the expected result:

> C:\testfolder\009028447_ test2.doc

Here is the entire code for the console application:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\testfolder";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "009*.doc");

        // Creates a string with all the elements of the array, separated by ", "
        string matchingFiles = string.Join(", ", files);

        Console.WriteLine(matchingFiles);
        // Since there is only one matching file, the above line only prints:
        // C:\testfolder\009028447_ test2.doc
    }
}
```

In conclusion, the code works. If you are getting other results, there must be other differences in your setup or code that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Lars ...its not about the code.Some environment problem .will update soon once i figured that out.

Comment: Why is the @ symbol there?

Comment: @Jotarata It is the [verbatim identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim). I usually use it to avoid escaping the backslashes in strings that hold folderpaths. So `"C:\\TEST\\Builds\\2019-12-03\\bin"` is the same as `@"C:\TEST\Builds\2019-12-03\bin"`

Answer (score -1):

If (and I did not check,) it is true that you are only receiving the wrong Files you should maybe use a foreach or linq to check if the Files match your criteria:

Foreach:

```
List<string> arrPaths = new List<string>();
Foreach(string strPath in Directory.GetFiles(filePath,".doc"))
{
if(strPath.EndsWith(".doc") & strPath.StartsWith("009"))
arrPaths.Add(strPath);
}
```

Linq:

```
List<string> arrPaths = Directory.GetFiles(filePath,".doc").Where(pths => pths.StartsWith("009") && pths.EndsWith(".doc")).ToList();
```

Both ways are more a workaround than a real solution, but I hope they're helping:)

*EDIT*

If you want to only get the Filenames i would subtract the filePath from your strPath like this:

Foreach:

```
arrPaths.Add(strPath.Replace(filePath + "\\", ""));
```

Linq:

```
List<string> arrPaths = Directory.GetFiles(filePath,".doc").Where(pt => pt.StartsWith("009") && pths.EndsWith(".doc")).Select(pths => pths.ToString().Replace(filePath + "\\", "").ToList();
```

Comment: Good approach for checking if there are any matching files. However, note that `Directory.GetFiles` returns the full path to the file, so the contents of the string is something like  `C:\myfolder\009_example.doc`.

Comment: Good addition @LarsKristensen, thus i would recommend to subtract the filePath from the strPath. Edited it in :)

Comment: @KonstantinJahnel does that lambda select cause  boolean to list casting issue?

Comment: @meet_aj not that I would know of it. I use it for pretty much every File-searching-Oparation and never had problems. So i can just recommend it with best of one's knowledge and belief :D

Comment: @meet_aj Yes it does and it should not! Replace Select with Where im honestly sorry :O

Comment: No problem @meet_aj feel free to mark it as the Answer :)